# Como hacer para que no me de mensaje de archivo en uso durante una conversion de un documento word a pdf usando interop

Tags: c#

Tengo el sigiente codigo :

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

```
                    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                    word.Visible = false;
                    word.ScreenUpdating = false;

                    FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
                    Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    doc.Activate();
               


                    object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                    object fileFormat = WordEx.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                    // Save document into PDF Format
                    doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                        ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                    object saveChanges = WordEx.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                    ((WordEx._Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    doc = null;


                    ((WordEx._Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    word = null;
```

pero a la hora de hacer la conversion me aroja el siguiente mensaje :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que debo hacer para que simplemente haga la conversion sin salirme la ventana anterior?

Answer (score 1):

Cierra todas las pestañas que tengas abiertas en ese momento que tengan que ver con el documento que piensas usar y que quieres que no te interfieran en ese momento con el.

Comment: Lo hago y aun estando todos los procesos cerrados me arroja esa ventana emergente

Comment: Eso arrojo luz a mi camino, aunque en mi ambiente habia cerrado todo al parecer en el servidor habia un proceso usando el mismo archivo... Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una memoria externa(una sd o algo parecido) activa la edición, ya que tal vez esté en modo solo lectura. O si no, solo cierra todos los programas que estén usando ese archivo